# Stack smashing detected with fgets() function in C

Tags: c, gcc, error-handling, io, stack-smash

I got this code:

```
while(!feof(fp))
{
   fgets(line,20,fp);
   puts(line);
}
```

`fp` is this file:

```
prova1
prova2
prova3prova4
prova5
```

The fact is: if the count parameter of the fgets function it's a lower number than 10 it works everything ok, but if it's greater it gives me a `stack smashing detected` error.

I think it's because I'm trying to read after EOF, but why when I'm trying to read just after it  works (like 8 characters per line) but when I put a count parameter of like 20 it gives me an error?

**NB:** the last line "prova5" is formed by 6 characters plus the '\0' I think, so 7. Why with 8 it's ok and it's not with 20?

EDIT:
I'm sorry, I forgot to include this declaration:

```
char line[] = " ";
```

Comment: A good ideom is to use `fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);` if `line` is an array (does not work if it is a pointer). Then it cannot write out of bounds because the specified size does not correspond to the array size.

Comment: Please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Lastly, C doesn't have any kind of bounds checking. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*, so just don't do it.

Comment: What's the declaration of `line`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you see "stack smashing detected" this usually means you write beyond the end of a locally declared array.

Comment: @ryyker: Well, that certainly removes any question that might have lingered about buffer overflow, doesn't it?

Comment: @FredLarson -  no doubts at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why with 8 it's ok and it's not with 20?*

This suggests the possibility that `line` has not been defined with enough space for containing 20 `char`. To be in line with your code snippet, `line` should be defined as:

```
char line[20];
```

Depending on your actual definition of `line`, you could be seeing results of [buffer overflow](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=buffer+overflow+in+C).  The reason it *seems* to work, then *not work* is *[undefined behavior](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNS7NTinf_xNYpfwWvrRgpkY_LwbgQ%3A1576073518835&ei=LvnwXcDDMsG20PEPnPuFuAY&q=undefined+behavior+in+c&oq=undefined+behavior&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.35i39l2j0l8.32176.35436..38531...0.2..0.68.941.18......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i273j0i131j0i67j0i10.aQyTuQdw5gk)*, which means any behavior is possible, and at unexpected times.

Also, you should consider replacing  `while(!feof(fp))` with `while(fgets(line, 20, fp))` which checks the return of `fgets` as a test, and exits upon seeing `NULL`.   `feof()` ([is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong))

```
while(fgets(line, 20, fp))//will exit loop upon a null return
{
   //do something with line;
   puts(line);
}
```

***EDIT*** to address clarification in comment:

If you declared `line` as a pointer:

char *line;

Then before using it in the rest of your code the pointer needs to be given an address with corresponding memory sufficient to contain 20 `char`.  This statement (and test to ensure memory was allocated) will do both:

```
line = calloc(20, 1);
if(line)
{
    //use line as described above
```

***EDIT 2*** to address new information in OP.

Since `line` was defined as (edited into OP later)

```
char line[] = " ";
```

It has room for only 1 character.  This *will* cause *[buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220212/buffer-overflow-in-c)*, and explains the inconsistent behavior that was observed (and written about in the post.)

The suggested way to define `line` to support what the code shown in your post needs is:

```
char line[20] = {0}; //space for 20 char, initialized to all zeros.
```

This, along with the other suggestions about replacing `feof` with `fgets` will improve the performance you see, and eliminate undefined behavior due to buffer overflow

Comment: I defined line as a pointer, I forgot to include the declaration in the question

Comment: @PierpaoloVesce - If you include that declaration in your original post, it will remove the reason your question was closed, and I will vote to re-open.  In the mean time, I will edit my answer to address how you can use the pointer with `malloc` to make your code work.  By the way, if you did not allocate memory before using your pointer, that would explain the undefined behavior that people (including me) were citing.

Comment: I would have defined line as a pointer but I changed into an array and yes if you can tell me how to use the pointer with malloc I would be so grateful, I'm so used to C++ that programming in C seems terrible

Comment: @PierpaoloVesce - Have updated my answer, and voted to reopen your post.  Thank you for updating.